# How can a get a value after inserting an id in a webpage in R

Tags: r, web-crawler

I'm new in R and getting data from the web, so would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction for my problem.
I have a list of id's, in the form of XXXXXXX-Y. I want to put each one of my id's in this webpage https://zeus.sii.cl/cvc_cgi/nar/nar_ingrut, where says "Ingrese Rut a consultar". After that I want it to click on "Consultar" and get the "Nombre del Contribuyente" and put it in a list.
I'm aware that this could take some time, but it would make my life a lot easier.

Comment: To get help with this, please share the code that you've managed to put together so far and ask about the specific step that you're stuck on or having trouble with.  As written, your question is asking for people to write your entire script for you.  Rselenium is one option for scraping data from the web in the manner you're describing, but there are others.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry it sounded like that, I was asking for guidance, not code :) I will try RSelenium, didn't know it existed